# Conditional JSON Sub-Schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, if-statement

I am trying to use the if-then-else statement in JSON but it's unsuccessful for now.

```
{
"type": "object",
"minProperties": 2,
"maxProperties": 2,
"properties": {
    "human": {
        "enum": [
            "Kids",
            "Adults"
        ]
    }
},

"if": {
    "properties": {
        "human": {
            "const": "Adults"
        }
    }
},
"then": {
    "properties": {
        "shoe_size": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 7,
            "maximum": 11
        }
    },
    "else": {
        "properties": {
            "shoe_size": {
                "type": "number",
                "minimum": 2,
                "maximum": 6
            }
        }
    }
},
"required": [
    "shoe_size",
    "human"
]
}
```

and as a result I should get something like:

```
{
 "human": "Adults",
 "shoe_size": 10
 }
```

Why are the values for the shoe_sizes not bounded to the mininum/maximum I assigned it to?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a nesting error, `else` must be on the same level as `if` and `then`:

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "minProperties": 2,
  "maxProperties": 2,
  "properties": {
    "human": {
      "enum": [
        "Kids",
        "Adults"
      ]
    }
  },

  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "human": {
        "const": "Adults"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "shoe_size": {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": 7,
        "maximum": 11
      }
    }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": {
      "shoe_size": {
        "type": "number",
        "minimum": 2,
        "maximum": 6
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "shoe_size",
    "human"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I test my JSON schema by generating payloads on 
https://json-schema-faker.js.org/# and it still gives me all kind of value types (boolean,string,numbers,null) for the shoe_size key. Do you think the tool is not designed for draft-v7, or is there still something wrong with the code?

Comment: I don't know this lib but no, seems not: https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/issues/466 and https://github.com/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#json-schema-specification-support (draft-v4)